How to study BTC ETFs?
Dears,
I have read a bit about BTC ETFs, but I am still quite lost in understanding this subject. I would like to know of someone could give me more information about this. For instance, let's take the following list of BTC ETFs.

ISHARES BITCOIN TRUST (IBIT);
FIDELITY WISE ORIGIN BITCOIN (FBTC);
Hashdex Bitcoin Futures ETF (DEFI);
BITWISE BITCOIN ETF (BITB);
ARK 21SHARES BITCOIN (ARKB).

I've been analyzing the behaviour of the prices of these ETFs, and compared with the BTC price. And I noticed that the BTC increase and/or decrease not necessarily implies in increase and/or decrease of a given ETF. Which, for me, is quite strange, since, AFAIK, the aim of an ETF for BTC is to reduce the risk of those interested in taking BTC as an investiment, rather than a hedge. Therefore, AFAI see, the ETF price should increase as the BTC price increases (even though not necessarily by the same rate), and decrease likewise.
I would like to know whether my reasoning is correct, and why.
Thanks and regards.
